# Possible? Recalculate Formula, after formula returned from Vlookup

Tags: excel, vlookup, excel-indirect

In ABCTable, column 4 are formulas example

```
0.8*(INDIRECT("G"&ROW())-200)

=VLOOKUP(K4,ABCTable,4,FALSE)
```

given condition of `k4`, i would like to call up the formula and recalculate in my current sheet.
but currently i only call up text or value of `(0.8*(INDIRECT("G"&ROW())-200))=-160`.

What can i do to make this work? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The value:

```
0.8*(INDIRECT("G"&ROW())-200)
```

is treated as text due to it not starting with an `=` sign.

---

To do work based on the value of a cell, use the `if` function

```
=IF(K4>0, "K4 greater then 0", "K4 is not greater then 0")
```